# Set domain on Many2one field value in Odoo

Tags: python, odoo, openerp-7, openerp-8

I have *Many2one* field witch is populated by *res.partner* module using custom domain.

When User selects one of values from *Many2one* field, I want to hide some fields based on selected value.

I try this:

```
<group string="My group name" attrs="{'invisible': [('mym2ofield', 'not ilike', 'mym2ofield value')]}">
```

But it does not work. How could I achieve it then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we need to add related field in your model. And than use that new related field in `attrs`

For example:

`type` is a char field on your many2one table.

```
class model_name(models.Model):
    _name = 'model.name'

    test_id = fields.Many2one('relation.table.name', string="Many2One Label")
    type = fields.Char(related='test_id.type', string="Type")
```

And then to your form:

```
<group string="group name" attrs="{'invisible': [('type', '!=', 'value')]}">
```

Comment: It doesnt work anyway. I make related field to be related to my `mym2ofield` `.name`. Now for example the `.name` of selection is `UAB "Senuku prekyba"`. I make `attrs="{'invisible': [('type', 'not ilike', 'Senuku prekyba')]}"` and it doesnt work

Comment: right side value is a char or selection field ? based on it's value we need to make related field.

Comment: `Many2one` field is selection and `type` field is `Char`

Comment: try with `attrs="{'invisible': [('type', '!=', 'Senuku prekyba')]}"` it will work.

Comment: Yes it work then but the choosen value is `UAB "Senuku prekyba"` thats why I use `ilike` operator, which should look for simmilar case, and `!=` looks for exact case and in this situation doesn't fit my needs

Comment: you could have tried `['!', ('type', 'ilike', 'Senuku prekyba')]`